# Animate SKSpriteNode's alpha while SKScene is paused

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

To pause my game, I pause the entire SKView and attempt to fade in a 'home' button:

```
self.addChild(pauseHomeButton) // Button node to return to home screen, with alpha 0
pauseHomeButton.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: .5))

self.speed = 0
self.isPaused = true
```

Because the SKView is paused, the SKAction is also paused. How can I still animate the alpha of this button so it fades in after the scene has been paused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pause the entire `SKView` or in your case more likely `SKScene`, you can't run any action on any of its child nodes.

So, goal is to pause just node which you need to pause. To achieve this, have one node for "game objects", etc. and another separate node for "control" nodes. So when one node will be paused, it won't affect the other node which won't be paused and you will be able to run actions on it or its childs

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var node = SKNode()
    var controlNode = SKNode()
}
```

now add game nodes etc. as child of `node` and stuff like this `pauseHomeButton`as child of `controlNode`

```
controlNode.addChild(pauseHomeButton)
```

Now just pause the `node` and also change its speed if you need to

```
pauseHomeButton.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: .5))

node.speed = 0
node.isPaused = true
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped to organise my nodes and works great.